# Вопросик по appendChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная:

```
var holdModals = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

Дальше идет цикл в котором создается `div`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('modal-drop');
  div.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vh';
  div.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vw';
  div.style.transitionDelay = Math.random() + 's';
  holdModals.appendChild(div);
}
```

Обратите внимание на `holdModals.appendChild(div)`. Поместил в цикле `div` в `holdModals`. Как после цикла поместить в `div` еще один элемент (к примеру `modalContainer`)

```
var modalContainer = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
```

Должно выглядеть так:

```
holdModals > div > modalContainer
```

Comment: в какой именно див надо добавить элемент?

Comment: @Grundy я цикле создал div ( var div = document.createElement('div');  )И  я переменную див "поместил" в holdModals.Мне надо modalContainer  "поместить" в div который находится в holdModals

Comment: в holdModals у тебя `num` дивов. В какой из них?

Answer (score 0):

```
holdModals.querySelector('.modal-drop:nth-child(' + divIndex + ')').appendChild(modalContainer);
```